# View Not Found While Trying To Use Route Model Binding

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to edit users so I added this as link:

`<a href="{{ route('users.edit', $user->name) }}" class="on-default edit-row">Edit</a>`

And at the Controller:

```
public function edit(User $user)
    {
        $roles = Role::where('slug', '!=', 'super-admin')->get();
        return view('admin.users.edit', compact('roles', 'user'));
    }
```

So as you can see I have called the `$user` from `User` Model but now the problem is, it says:

**404 | NOT FOUND**

However if I remove `User $user` to `$id`, it will be working fine !

So what is going wrong here ? How can I properly use Route Model Binding here ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the route look like in your `routes/web/php` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the user's id instead of the users name to your route.

```
<a href="{{ route('users.edit', $user->id) }}" class="on-default edit-row">Edit</a>
```

Otherwise, if you want to use the user's name you have two options

1. Add getRouteKeyName to user.php

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name';
}
```

2. Customize implicit route model binding directly in your web.php

```
Route::get('/users/{user:name}/edit', function (User $user) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: NICO beat me to the answer so I removed mine. The only extra point I would make is that you can pass the id as NICO says or the whole model `route('users.edit', $user)`